# Is it possible to explore region in event horizon by using charged spaceship?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, electric-fields, charge, event-horizon

From this

[Overcharging a black hole](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61118/overcharging-a-black-hole)

If black hole has a charge, it has electric field.

If I charge same charged to spaceship, if it is possible to make repelled force equal to gravitational force.

Is this ways possible to explore region in event horizon ?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/61118/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that question (It use different word.). Now, I get the answer. Thank you very much.