# What did Feynman mean by "gravity itself is a pseudo force"?

Tags: newtonian-gravity

Feynman writes:

> One very important feature of pseudo forces is that they are always proportional to the masses; the same is true of gravity. The possibility exists, therefore that **gravity itself is a pseudo force**. ... It might seem all right to consider gravity to be a pseudo force, to say that we are all held down because we are accelerating upward... Einstein found that **gravity could be considered a pseudo force only at one point at a time...**

Now, how can gravity be a pseudo force? What did Feynman meant by saying this statement? Is gravity really a pseudo force? If so, why?

Comment: The force of gravity depends on the coordinate system. In a free falling coordinate system (like aboard the ISS) there is no force of gravity, at all. This is a very important statement on which all of general relativity rests.

Comment: See also [Why do we still need to think of gravity as a force?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61899/why-do-we-still-need-to-think-of-gravity-as-a-force)

Comment: @John Rennie: Sir, I really do want to know why gravity is a pseudo force. But none of the questions linked do answer why gravity is a pseudo force. Really want an answer:-C

Comment: I wanted to know why gravitational force is a pseudo force. So,why is it duplicate??

Comment: The marked duplicate why gravitation is not a force never does concern with why it is pseudo force. I wanted an answer. But it was marked duplicate with a quo that never really asked mine. And more also, there is no proper answer there.

Comment: @user36790 - In Newtonian physics, pseudo forces (or fictitious forces, or inertial forces) result from trying to use F=ma to explain motion from the perspective of a non-inertial frame. The same is true in general relativity. The catch: The two theories differ massively on what constitutes an inertial frame. The key difference with regard to whether gravitation is a "real" or a "fictitious" force is that a free-falling object forms the basis of a local inertial frame in GR. An object at rest on the surface of a planet? That's close to inertial in Newtonian mechanics, not at all close in GR.

Comment: Why the switch? First off, inertial frames are global (universal) in extent in Newtonian mechanics. That doesn't make a bit of sense in GR with its curved space-time. Secondly, and more importantly, the [equivalence principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle) comes into play. Einstein used his [elevator thought experiment](http://www.einstein-online.info/spotlights/equivalence_principle) as a way to elicit problems with the Newtonian concept of an inertial frame and the equivalence principle.

Comment: @David Hammen: Thanks for these brilliant cnmments. Then what is inertial frame in Newtonian Mechanics is not at all inertial in GR.