# Gravity as a fundamental force

Tags: general-relativity, forces, gravity

In Dr.Einstein's theory of General Relativity-- he goes to great lengths to explain how the force of gravity is merely an illusion and in the case of the falling apple-- it is the earth accelerating to meet the apple's inertial frame.
But it is well known that gravity is one of the four fundamental forces.
I would like to know the reason for this apparent contradiction. Is it or is it not a force?

Comment: You might be interested to read [how-we-know-gravity-is-not-just-a-force](https://www.universetoday.com/108740/how-we-know-gravity-is-not-just-a-force/)

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/61899/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/219306/2451 and links therein.