# Why are we still considering gravity as one of four fundamental forces?

Tags: general-relativity, forces, gravity

if gravity is just bending of spacetime according to general relativity why are we still considering it as one of the 4 fundamental forces. https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/12408/ this link provides that gravity is not force but just bending of spacetime so why it is the way it was?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/61899/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/219306/2451 and links therein.

Comment: thanks Qmechanic