# When is gravity a force?

Tags: general-relativity, forces, gravity

We all know that gravity is best explained by general relativity which says mass curves space-time. This means that gravity is not a force but an acceleration and we are “falling” towards massive things. (Not sure if I worded that correctly. Correct me if not)

I’ve read that gravity isn’t a force but acts like one. Like the centrifugal force. A fictitious force.

My question is:

When can we say that gravity acts like a force and when can’t we?

Is there a time we can’t say it’s a force at all and say it’s an acceleration?

Does general relativity actually say it is a force and I’m just misunderstanding something?

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/219306/50583

Comment: Not being highly conversant in general relativity, it is my understanding that for weak gravitational fields, the results of general relativity do not differ significantly from Newton's law of gravitation. So for weak gravitational fields,  one can view gravity as a force.

Comment: Informally, "gravity" is always a force, as "gravity" implies Newton. In GR, gravitational phenomena fall under "gravitation".

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/578892/195139