# Why is gravity considered a force of nature?

Tags: general-relativity, forces, gravity, curvature, interactions

Wouldn’t gravity be considered an effect to the other forces?  An object of a given mass warps space time.  The larger the mass, the greater the warpage.  There is no graviton exchanged between the mass creating the warp, and all other objects?  So in a sense, the other forces actually create gravity through their effects.  Without them, there could be no gravity.

Comment: Your second lines shows that the other forces aren't needed to provide gravity/curvature, so why do you think that gravity cannot exist without the others?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If gravity isn't a force, then why do we learn in school that it is?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/219306/)