# What constitutes a force?

Tags: forces, gravity, definition

There are a few questions on here about why Gravity is not a force, but I'm having trouble grasping why exactly.

It sounds to me that Gravity is *not* a force because it is simply a by-product of mass on spacetime.  How does this differ from the strong nuclear force?  Are the other forces not an effect of the presence of a particle?

I apologize if this is an overly simple question, I'm not well-versed in physics.

Comment: Possibly related to this post: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/61899/

Answer (score 0):

> It sounds to me that Gravity is not a force because it is simply a by-product of mass on spacetime.

The force in general, including its particular case the Gravity, is a byproduct of mass, space and time because it is measured in $kg*m/s^2$.