# Why is gravity so weak?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity, forces, interactions

How does physics explain the enormous disparity between the gravitational scale and the typical mass scale of the elementary particles? In other words, why is gravity so much weaker than the other forces, like electromagnetism?

Comment: More on gravity as the weakest force: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4243/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57228/2451 and links therein.