# Gravity Vs Electrostatics

Tags: gravity

**Why is electrostatic force significantly stronger than the gravitational force?** 
Is there any deeper reason other than the fact that coulumb's constant is much bigger than gravitational constant?
is it because gravitational force is a consequence of curvature of space time and related to object's inertia, where as, electrostatic force is due to interaction of charges with electric field?

Comment: Superficially, you can say it's because gravity has a relatively tiny coupling constant.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57228/2451 and links therein.