# Is the theory of electromagnetism very incomplete in physical interpretation?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, gravity, newtonian-gravity, charge

Just like in Newtonian gravity, do we simply accept charge being naturally attracted to the opposite charge with a very similar Newtonian style force? (Coulomb)
Shouldn't there be a meaningful theory of electromagnetism like in the interpretation of general relativity? Where we understand that gravity is an effect of space-time distortion attributed to mass.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/548790/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/148028/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57228/2451 and links therein.

Comment: There is always a turn where you say, that we have this for the grant. The same goes for Newtonian gravity, space-time, or electromagnetism.

Comment: @Qmechanic yup exactly what I needed. Thanks