# Is fundamentally, gravity being much weaker than electromagnetism a myth?

Tags: electromagnetism, newtonian-gravity, quantum-electrodynamics, fine-tuning

I came across these two, conflicting conclusions information sources comparing at the quantum-scale distances (e.g. distance between two protons)  the strength of Gravity Vs. Electromagnetism.

I understand that at macro-scale and even microscopic distances most of the matter in the universe is *charge neutral* (i.e. opposite charges inside matter cancel out) which however is not true for gravity in matter which is omnipresent and cannot be cancelled out and therefore for macroscopic distances it is the dominant force in our universe.

However, at the quantum scale of sizes, matter seems to be fundamentally dominated more by charge and mass and gravity becomes negligible thus the [hierarchy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchy_problem). Actually according to [this article of the two](https://astroquizzical.com/astroquizzical/not-entirely-related-to-spaceastronomy-but-why) 36 orders of magnitude weaker than electromagnetism.

**However,** according to [this article here](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/myths-of-physics-2-gravit_b_5718233), this is a myth! Is this explanation just a  kind of a formalism artifact non-physical interpretation or is this actually true?

Are there quantum LHC experiments to measure gravity at the quantum scale or is this only theoretically derived?

I am confused, and ask for a canonical answer?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units#Significance

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/582842/226902, https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/570443/226902 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/144908/226902

Comment: In the given article the conclusion seems to be different than the one stated in OP. The last sentence is: "In short, it makes no sense to even ask what is the relative strength of gravity and electromagnetism"

Comment: Well, it actually also says inside "If you define the dimensionless strength of gravity using the Planck mass you get exactly $1$. In the case, gravity is 137 times stronger than electromagnetism."

Comment: @ConnorBehan Still, the force in Newtons of the electrostatic repulsion force between two protons is much much larger than their gravitational attraction. IMHO, it is the level of coherency that is the resolution to the hierarchy problem. EM dipole forces are much more coherent forces than gravity.

Comment: This always strikes me as an apples and oranges thing.

Comment: Actually everything is duplicate in PSE :)

Comment: What is a “coherent” force, and how does one quantify that coherence to show that “EM dipole forces are much more coherent forces than gravity”?