# Gravity ‘The weak force’

Tags: gravity

Gravity is sometimes described as the weak force. How can something that has an infinite range, i.e. Supposedly have an effect on matter at the other side of our universe, possibly be called weak ?

Comment: Strength isn't  determined by range

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does it mean to say "Gravity is the weakest of the forces"?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4243/)

Comment: Surely the range of a force should have a relationship to it’s strength

Comment: I had a look at the above question, but it does not answer the question I have asked

Comment: The linked possible duplicate has good answers, but FWIW, as a matter of style, it is a description that I prefer to avoid because it leads to confusion with the force mediated by W and Z bosons https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_interaction, and because it tends to do more the confound than to clarify the issue because it presumes a comparison in a frame of reference that isn't natural to a lay person (i.e. the phrase is a form of "nerd view." http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=26238#more-26238 that only makes sense to people who already understand what one is trying to communicate).

Comment: Ohwilleke - what you have written makes no sense, you probably meant it in a derogatory way. My question is an honest one and deserves a more genuine response.

Comment: You can have strong long-range forces, weak long-range forces, strong short-range forces, and weak short-range forces. Electromagnetism and gravity are long-range, but gravity is more than a trillion trillion trillion times weaker than EM.

Comment: If gravity were not so weak, we would have to take it into account when doing atomic physics, chemistry, nuclear physics, condensed matter physics, etc. It can be ignored until things are astronomical-sized.

Comment: Harvey, there IS a force called the weak force but it has nothing to do with gravity. Gravity is a weak force, but it is not THE Weak Force.