# Why is gravity called the weakest force?

Tags: forces, gravity, interactions

Why is gravity called the weakest force? How do we even compare forces?

I am not talking about the natural values of the forces that we normally experience in our daily lives.... I mean to say, we don't know the magnitude of any force to it's *extremity*, right? It can always be larger...

**So on what basis do we compare forces in general? What is the basis for a fair comparison in this case?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does it mean to say "Gravity is the weakest of the forces"?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4243/)

(see also the linked questions on that page, which has many other variants of this question)

Comment: @Rococo it does, thanks a lot!